# Show the selected ID with Bootsrap Dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I created a dropdown menu and I want to display certain contents within a php file. Unfortunately When I clicking on the sub item the all elements displaying although I just want to show one element (in my case on div with id). I would appreciate I somebody tell me how can i achieve that only the selected id appear.

**My dropdown menu:**

```
        <li class="parent ">
        <a href="#">
            <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-1"><svg class="glyph stroked chevron-down"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-down"></use></svg></span> Dropdown 
        </a>
        <ul class="children collapse"  id="sub-item-1">
            <li>
                <a class=""  href="foo.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="dropdown_show1" >
                    <svg class="glyph stroked chevron-right"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"></use></svg> Sub Item 1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class=""  href="foo.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="dropdown_show2">
                    <svg class="glyph stroked chevron-right"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"></use></svg> Sub Item 2
                </a>
         </li>
            <li>
                <a class="" href="#">
                    <svg class="glyph stroked chevron-right"><use xlink:href="#stroked-chevron-right"></use></svg> Sub Item 3
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

**My foo.php**

```
 <div class="collapse" id="dropdown_show1">  
            <p> test1</p>
            </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="dropdown_show2>  
            <p> test1</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand everything but .. first there's a typo in your `foo.php` it should be `collapse` instead of `collepase`... Secondly, why are you trying to use PHP?

Comment: Provide more details.

Comment: The php can be html too, the problem is the same. When I click at the `Sub Item 1` the `Sub Item 2` appear too, despite I refer to another div (`id="dropdown_show2"`), so the contents of `d="dropdown_show1"`and `"dropdown_show2"` are appearing.

Comment: Since my last comment I reached that just one element appear, but just for a moment. The drop-down change back to the normal postion (when the sub items hidden).